# Трое сестриц — Трое братьев: собирательные числительные

Tags: этимология, числительные, история, род, собирательные-числительные

Наверное, все со школы помнят, что собирательные числительные *двое, трое, четверо* и так далее (двестивосемьдесятдевятеро?) употребляются в основном со словами мужского и общего рода (если называвают мужчин), существительными типа "ножницы" и существительными вроде "дети". Тем не менее, даже в корпусе есть парочка старых примеров со словами женского рода.

Судя по всему, причина ненормативности сочетаний с женским родом лежит в истории происхождения слов для собирательных числительных.

Вопрос — и что же это за происхождение? Как оно объясняет, что собирательные числительные в  современном литературном языке ассоциируются с *мужским* родом, но никак не с женским?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Числительное как особая часть речи складывалась в русском языке в течение длительного времени (с 14 по 18 век). Что касается собирательных числительных, то они изначально составляли особый класс, а именно класс СОБИРАТЕЛЬНО-РАЗДЕЛИТЕЛЬНЫХ СЛОВ.  Раньше говорили: "на ужинѣ двоя рыба" -  это означало рыба двух сортов. Со временем такое значение «деления на группы»  сошло на нет, и собирательные слова  стали  дублировать количественные числительные.

Также происходило  сужение области применения этой группы числительных. Если изначально во всех славянских языках они изменялись по родам и числам и сочетались с любыми существительными, то в современном русском языке  осталась одна  форма - ед. ч. ср. р. При этом собирательные числительные  в основном могут сочетаться (помимо pluralia tantum) только с существительными мужского и общего рода.

По словам Виноградова,  «в оборотах двое мужчин (но две женщины), трое крестьян (но три крестьянки) и т. д. пережиточно отражается та стадия в развитии языка, когда категория одушевленности еще не сложилась, а категория лица охватывала названия лиц только мужского пола».

Интересно что форма двое/трое еще в 19 веке существовала наряду со старой формой двои/трои, которая сочеталась с неодушевленными предметами, например: "Остановимся, может быть, сутки на двои" (Фонвизин). "Он мог так пробыть хоть трои сутки" (Гончаров).У Пушкина: "Сделаны были трои триумфальных ворот" ("Материалы для истории Петра I").

Утверждение грамматики собирательных числительных и в 19 веке вызывало ожесточенные споры между лингвистами, например: "Мы употребляем двое... Мы не смеем употребить двои... но народ употребляет обе формы, он говорит: двои ключи. Образованный или лучше испорченный наш язык оскорбляется таким выражением и называет его простонародным... Наше употребление: двое — не смело и даже смешно, мы говорим: двое молодцов, но не скажем двое человек, не скажем двое женщин, двое ведер, предаваясь какому-то темному и прихотливому такту слуха, привычки" (К. Аксаков).

Answer (score 1):

Вы выбрали подобный тон? Принимается. Теперь не обижайтесь!!! Отвечаю на Ваши бредни: "Думаю, врать всё-таки нужно аккуратнее, можно ведь и поймать за руку. Японский, стало быть, к восточным языкам не относится? И кто вам вообще сказал, что английский сформировался на базе латинского? Тогда уж и русский оттуда же. Хороший язык, латинский, раз уж всё из него, связанное и никак не связанное."
- Японский язык претерпел ЧИСТКУ от американизмов после II Мировой войны. То, что латинский - один из ОСНОВНЫХ источников формирования английского языка мне говорили на кафедре английского языка одного из московский инязов. Вас тогда ещё и в планах не было и некому было нести наивный лепет и банальности. Ваши банальности и глупости следуют ниже:
"В русском языке достаточно мало более-менее новых заимствований" - Сейчас их рекордное количество: за последние 20 лет их больше, чем за предыдущие 200 лет."По-видимому, в последнее время так много заимствований, потому что в мире появляется очень много нового (компьютеры, конечно же)" - Как будет "компьютер" по-японски? А по-китайски? А по-арабски? А по-французски? А по-армянски? Ну что получается - только русский поллюционирует! Уважающие себя языки не заимствуют ДАЖЕ "компьютер" и ВСЕ другие сверхновые слова, как в технике, так и в АйТи, не говоря уже про манагеров, спикеров, эксов, мэров, глобализаций и т.д. Этот "аргумент" настолько тухлый, что только человек, который не знает ни одного иностранного языка кроме английского, может продолжать его тупо талдычить. "Русский заставляет работать по своим законам" - это самообман. Я могу привести десятки примеров, как русский язык подминается под английский на уровне фонетики, грамматики, лексики. "У нас ведь и звуковая система достаточно развита (не приходится думать, как бы передать слово), и падежи уже готовы. Даже для глаголов есть устоявшиеся практики (очень часто из заимствованного слова легко образовать глагол на -ить, -овать или -ировать)." - Этот лепет вообще невозможно серьезно комментировать.

Comment: 1. Английский и латинский языки из разных ветвей, и лексики английский набрался из латинского относительно недавно.  2. Компьютер в японском "кампю:та:" или "пасокон". Просто поверьте на слово, японский как позаимствовал в своё время кучу китайских слов, так и в XX веке позаимствовал и кучу английских. Это и понятно, для достаточно бедной японской фонетики это как свежий воздух - много комбинаций, которые китайские заимствования дать не могут.

Comment: Насчёт же числа заимствований — посмотрите список. Общее число, конечно, огромно. Вот только в английском французские заимствования во всех слоях языка. У нас же недавние английские заимствования на третьих ролях. Более старые французские/немецкие — на вторых. Если брать основные слова, они как были родные лет 100-200 назад, так в основном и остались. Какие-то сменились другими ("очи" уже давно заменены на "глаза"— *шары*).

Comment: @Shady_arc По-японски "компьютер" - "пасокон"? Ответ принят - японцы ДАЖЕ компьютер назвали своим словом!!! Что же говорить про бытовые слова, которые сейчас активно вытесняются из русского...

Comment: @Гусляр это сокращение от "па:сонару компю:та" (personal computer). Ещё раз — я готов предположить, что вы знаете какие-то из перечисленных языков (впрочем, с таким узким кругозором — уже не уверен), но, пожалуйста, не надо приводить в пример японский, о котором вы не знаете почти ничего. Одна из причин, почему в бытовом японском языке английские заимствования легко приживаются — китайские заимствования порой слишком непонятны: в японском и так бедная звуковая система, а когда они проецируют произношение иероглифов на неё, получается не так много разных слогов.

Comment: Например, в японском возможно слово "нано".  Или "сорока". Но таких слов в нём нет. Т.е. вместо создания новых коротких и ёмких слов, комбинация иероглифов с китайскими чтениями даст очередные вариации на тему ко/сэй/сё/хэй/хан и т.п. — например сочетанию 較正 "ко:сей" в речи соответствует куча омонимов (зато в научной статье идеограммы читаются быстро и понятно — но в речи нужно будет аккуратно все редкие сочетания перевести на "устный" язык, часть из них заменив на японские слова или европейские заимствования).